# Azure PowerShell - Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration : throws object not set error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am writing an automation script for Infrastructure creation in Azure which contains the following code:

```
Azure-LoginAndPickSubscription  -azureSubscriptionId $CONFIG_AZURE["SUBSCRIPTIONID"] `
                                    -azureUsername $CONFIG_AZURE["USERNAME"] `
                                    -azureEncryptedPassword $CONFIG_AZURE["PASSWORD"] `
                                    -passwordKeyFilePath "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY\private.key"





    $solutionRoot = Split-Path -Path $SCRIPT_DIRECTORY -Parent

    $storContext = (New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName mystorename -StorageAccountKey "mystoragekey")

    Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration  "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY\NewDSC\InitialConfig.ps1" -ContainerName "windows-powershell-dsc"  -Force -StorageContext $storContext
```

The last line (Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration) throws an error:

> Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. At
>   C:\temp\Base.Deploy\ARM.Create.ps1:38 char:5
>   +     Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration  "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY\NewDSC\Initia ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration], NullReferenceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.Extensions.DSC.PublishAzureVMDscConfigurationCommand

I have checked the script (InitialConfig.ps1) exists, and the $storContext object is populated. Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: It will be difficult to say why is it failing. InitialConfig.ps1 could be incorrect. Can you post the script here. Will help better diagnose this issue.

Comment: Hi @Rena-MSFT, thanks for commenting - I have since run this with no problems on a different server with an older version of the cmdlet installed (1.1.5) - so I'm guessing this may be something to do with the new cmdlet version (2.0.1) used on the problem server. I can also run `Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration  "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY\NewDSC\InitialConfig.ps1" -ConfigurationArchivePath "C:\temp\dsc\MyConfig.zip" -Force` fine on the problem server..

Answer (score 0):

@Carl,
From your PowerShell code and error message, it seems that you used the ARM mode in your PowerShell. However, your code should use the ASM mode. I recommedn you can use Switch-AzureMode to switch your powershell mode and then run your code again.  Please refer to this blog to check their difference (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/07/20/introducing-azure-resource-manager-cmdlets-for-azure-powershell-dsc-extension/ ). Like this

```
PS C:\> Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager
PS C:\>Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureServiceManagement
```

Any results, please let me know.

Comment: thanks for this - it pointed me in the right direction :) I had intended to use ARM! My final working code looks like this - `Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -ConfigurationPath "InitialConfig.ps1" -ContainerName  "windows-powershell-dsc" -Force -StorageAccountName "MyStorageAccount"`

Comment: Nice. Glad to hear that you have resolved this issue. You used the right mode in the powershell in this time.